# Excel.Range.Find always returns null

Tags: c#, .net, excel

He everyone!
I am new to office embedded developing.
I have a part of code which has to find value in a range but its always returns as null: (i - is iterator index)

```
 xlWorkSheet.Cells[100, 100] = karts[i].minTime.ToString();
 Excel.Range a = xlWorkSheet.Range["D2", "N2"].Find(xlWorkSheet.Cells[100, 100]);
 if(a!=null)
            a.Borders.Color = 3;
```

So when I found a value in range i want to border it but if is always skipped by null.

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find(VS.80).aspx it's supposed to return null if it does not find what you are looking for. Are you sure one of the 11 cells between D2 and N2 contains exactly what you have in karts[i].minTime.ToString()?

Comment: Yes ,iam pretty sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write

```
while(a!=null)
{
a.Borders.Color = 3;
}
```

Because Find will only look for the first object all acording to Microsoft [How to:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a.aspx)